# Responsive Google Ads inside accordion or tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, accordion, adsense

Is there a workaround for Responsive Google Ads to be displayed inside Bootstrap type accordions or tabs? The problem is that the accordion uses hidden elements and the inserted ad wont display and i get the this js error from the adsense code:

```
TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for a workaround, because we can't implement AdSense ads in accordions / tabs. It is against policies: AdSense ads shouldn't be hidden.

Modification of the AdSense ad code
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1354736